# How to play a video with a different audio track?

Tags: windows-vista, video, audio

I want to connect the output of my laptop to a projector and beam a movie on the wall.

The movie has video and audio, but I would like to be able to play different audio tracks while the video is playing.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use VLC to remove the default audio (`Media` -> `Convert/Save...`; Check `Video` and `Keep original video track` in the profile options, uncheck `Audio`. Use a new profile to leave other settings intact!).

VLC can open additional audio at `Media` -> `Advanced Open File...` -> `Show more options`.

Download: [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

Comment: The menu labels seem to have changed. Now it's Media > Open multiple files. Pick the video file in the normal file selection, then tick "show more options" and "play another media sychronously". In the browse input that appears, select the audio to play. You can then play or save this merged media. Image showing the window: http://i.imgur.com/alEIgSc.png (from VLC 2.2.1).

Comment: The steps work for Windows. How does one play a video with a different audio track in VLC for Android or VLC for iOS? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Using the instructions from Tamschi, on this page, I was able to do a one-shot play of a video with another file as its audio track.  The following instructions do not make any permanent changes.

I tested this with VLC on Windows 10, though every VLC running anywhere should work exactly the same.

For many alternate audio tracks, I believe you would select more than one audio track at step 11.  I did not have more than one audio track to test this with.

1. Launch VLC, or open your video file in VLC
2. Media > Open Multiple Files
3. (The "Open Media" window)
4. Add your main video file
5. (The file selection window)
6. Click "Show more options" at the lower-left
7. Click "Play another media synchronously" just underneath
8. Click "Browse" to the right
9. (The "Open Media" window)
10. Add your audio file
11. (The file selection window)

    - Only select that audio file, and not more than one file.
    - Do not select the video track.
12. Click "Select" at the bottom-right
13. (You will now see all three fields filled out)

    - Click "Play" at the bottom-right
    - Do not click the down-arrow next to "Play".
    - Your video will begin playing. Pause it.
14. Right-click in the video > Audio > Audio Track

    - Your new audio track will appear in the list of audio tracks. Select it.
    - Play your video.

It may take a few moments of play for VLC to get things sorted out. You may see video corruption or stuttering. Be patient!

A complete tutorial with screenshots can be found at http://blog.spiralofhope.com?p=18574

Comment: Tried this, but the last step from: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Play_an_external_audio_track_for_a_video/ does not show up: 

Go to Audio -> Audio track -> Track 2. (If you have more than one track available, pick the one that corresponds to the desired audio overlay.)

Comment: This answer worked for me in testing (including the last step, as Track 2) on Windows 7 with VLC 3.0.11 (June 2020) with a standard `.mp4` video file and `.mp3` music file.