# How can I play and seek video and audio from separate sources simultaneously?

Tags: linux, video

I have these files:

- `video.mkv` (with no sound)
- `audio_en.mp3`
- `audio_ru.mp3`
- `audio_pl.mp3`

And I want to simultaneously play `video.mkv` and `audio_en.mp3` and simultaneously seek in those files (move forward and backward) while playing.

Even better would be playing and seeking at the same time in multiple audio files.

- `video.mkv`
- `audio_env.mp3`
- `audio_music.mp3`
- `audio_spek.mp3`
- `audio_translation.mp3`

The reason I want to do this is obvious, large files and many different audio tracks. That's why I don't want to concatenate vid and audio1, vid and audio2...

Comment: It's also possible with VLC: http://superuser.com/questions/244760/how-to-play-a-video-with-a-different-audio-track

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cinelerra](http://cinelerra.org/) or other software for video, audio manipulation can play from multiple sources. So it can seek (play) in multiple sources.

MPlayer can also play from separate sources. Which is basically what I was looking for:

```
mplayer video.mkv -audiofile audio_en.mp3
```

In older versions of MPlayer, the option was called just `-audio`.

Comment: I think the option nowadays is `-audiofile`.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, but I do not know the rules for copy-pasting an answer elsewhere.

---

For a solution, using VLC, to choose a new audio track, see:

https://superuser.com/a/1077106/355105
A complete tutorial with screenshots can be found at http://blog.spiralofhope.com?p=18574

This solution does not make permanent changes.

Comment: "My apologies, but I do not know the rules for copy-pasting an answer elsewhere." The rules are don't do it. Flag the question as a duplicate if the answer is elsewhere on [su]. Otherwise use proper attribution. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing)