# 2020: To quickly and efficiently play an external audio track in sync with a video?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, video, sync

To quickly and efficiently play an external audio track in sync with a video?

[How to play a video with a different audio track?](https://superuser.com/questions/244760/how-to-play-a-video-with-a-different-audio-track/1077106#1077106)

https://superuser.com/a/1077106/183467

Tried this, but the last step from:
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Play_an_external_audio_track_for_a_video/
does not show up:

> Go to Audio -> Audio track -> Track 2.

(If you have more than one track available, pick the one that corresponds to the desired audio overlay.)

This is not working anymore, is too cumbersome and out of date and we would like a simpler cleaner faster method.

PS: OS - Win 8.1 x64

Answer (score 2):

> This [VLC solution] is not working anymore[.]

Testing a standard `.mp4` and `.mp3` file with the current build of VLC 3.0.11 (June 2020) on Windows 7, `Track 2` was displayed as an option to hear an external audio file along with the video file playing in VLC, as indicated in the relevant links in your original question.

Also note that the answer in the first link that describes the `Track 2` method was apparently conducted successfully under Windows 10. So this method appears to still work, at least in certain cases.

> We would like a simpler, cleaner, faster method.

You may want to have a look at [MPV](https://mpv.io/) then rather than VLC.

- The download page for MPV is [here](https://mpv.io/installation/), including unofficial binaries for Windows.
- An official [online reference manual](https://mpv.io/manual/) (HTML) is available, as well as an [unofficial PDF version](https://mpv.srsfckn.biz/manual.pdf).

---

*Anecdotally, the [unofficial Windows builds by shinchiro](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpv-player-windows/files/) work well enough and are probably the ones I would generally recommend. Just download the latest version of MPV as a `.7z` ([7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)) archive from either the `32bit` or `64bit` directories on Sourceforge.*

---

**Example**

Assuming you used a shinchiro build (above), simply extract the `.7z` archive to wherever you want MPV to live. You can then run ex:

```
C:\path\to\mpv.exe video.ext -audio-file audio.ext
```

to play a video file and audio file in sync, with the audio file replacing the audio track of the video during playback.

If you add `mpv.exe` to your Windows Path, you can shorten this to ex.:

```
mpv video.ext -audio-file audio.ext
```

Note that `video.ext` and `audio.ext` are the paths to your video and audio files, respectively. Full paths that contain spaces need to be surrounded with double-quotes (`""`), whether this is the path to `mpv.exe`, `video.ext` or `audio.ext`.

---

> Will we have to resort to command line instead of GUI?

If you check the [Wikipedia page for MPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpv_(media_player)), there are a number of players that are based around MPV/MPlayer (of which MPV is technically a fork), but there are only two (that I am aware of) which potentially support "easy" methods of combining video and audio via their GUIs. These are [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/) and [Baka MPlayer](http://bakamplayer.u8sand.net/).

---

*Unfortunately, at the time of this writing, the current version of SMPlayer wasn't working correctly for me (but your experiences may vary).*

---

**Baka MPlayer**

Using Baka MPlayer to play an external audio file over a video is similar to using VLC but with (slightly) fewer steps. After you [download Baka MPlayer](http://bakamplayer.u8sand.net/installation.php) and extract the archive:

1. Open a video file with `Baka Mplayer.exe`.
2. Playback will begin immediately. Pause the video and rewind it to the beginning. Note that <kbd>Space</kbd> will toggle video playback and holding the right-arrow key <kbd>◄</kbd> will rewind the video quickly. You can, of course, use the Pause (<kbd>||</kbd>) and/or Rewind (<kbd>|◄</kbd>) controls in the GUI as well.
3. To add an external audio file to play over the video, open  *Playback → Audio Tracks → Add File...*:

*ex. Loading An External Audio File*

[image: Baka Player - Loading An External Audio File - Screenshot]

4. Select the external audio file from the standard Widows file selection dialog that appears.
5. You should then be able press <kbd>Space</kbd> or Play (<kbd>►</kbd>) in the GUI to begin playing the video file with the external audio track (it will be selected automatically).

**Notes**

- SMPlayer should have a similar menu option to Step 3 above (though not an exact duplicate, obviously).
- Baka MPlayer is old. Though its GitHub page apparently isn't entirely dead, it hasn't been updated since 2015. Not exactly a drawback per se (plenty of older Windows programs work fine on modern systems) but if you encounter any issues with it, it seems unlikely they will be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: Will we have to resort to commandline instead of GUI?

Comment: MPV is (mostly) a command line application. There are a number of [GUI players built around MPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpv_(media_player)) which you can investigate, but I believe only a couple of those projects would likely fit your requirements. Specifically these are [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/) (which doesn't work for me on Windows, but you may have a different experience) and [Baka MPlayer](http://bakamplayer.u8sand.net/). I've updated my answer with instructions on using Baka MPlayer, but be aware that it currently isn't under active development.

Comment: Will check out the GUI players this weekend/ next week and update. Thanks. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you find something satisfactory. =)