# VLC: Play network video and audio from different source?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I wish to play a network stream which comes in a format of `m3u8`.

Unfortunately video and audio are in separated files, so I tried to open a network stream and then "Play another media synchronously (extra audio file, ...)":

[image]

The problem is that VLC seems to buffer 1 second of the video, then play it, then buffer 1s of audio then play it (with video stalled). So kind of a chess table: VAVAVAV.

Is there any option to really buffer and synchonise the video and audio if both are coming from network?

Using 2 separated VLC instances I can play both video and audio, but synchronizing them are a but tidious work.

Also, (how) can I change the prebuffer (or cache, or whatever) to really buffer at least 1 minute of video AND audio, and then start playback?

I don't mind waiting at the beginning. But now video stalls in every 5-10seconds for a short time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play a video with a different audio track?](https://superuser.com/questions/244760/how-to-play-a-video-with-a-different-audio-track)

Comment: No, as I stated: it buffers 1s video, then plays the video (without audio), then buffers 1s audio and plays audio (without video): VAVAVAVAV. It might work well for local files though.

Comment: Try it with local files. It might be that one of the sources is slow to access and is lagging.

Comment: What is the source? Is there a reason the two sources are separate? If this is a web stream, often the lower resolution sources can be a single stream.

Comment: Sources are from network. Works perfectly with 2 separate VLC instances. (Just I have sync issues, i.e. sound comes earlier or later than video, but both are fluid)